# Problema ao instalar Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Bom dia galera, estava tentando instalar o Numpy nessa máquina... Rodei o comando "conda install numpy" ai deu certo...mas quando rodei "pip install numpy", ele retorna esse erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente, baseado no erro que você recebe, está faltando você instalar o pacote ipykernel, jogando no google achei duas soluções:

1ª: Usando o pip:

Primeiro certifique-se que seu pip está na versão 9.0>>

```
python2 -m pip --version
```

Depois use os comandos:

```
python2 -m pip install ipykernel
python2 -m ipykernel install --user
```

2ª: Usando o ambiente virtual e Conda

```
conda create -n ipykernel_py2 python=2 ipykernel
source activate ipykernel_py2    # On Windows, remove the word 'source'
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

[FONTE](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html)